# TFS with different binaries folder for different projects

Tags: tfs, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I've got a solution with Silverlight projects, a couple Web applications and some Windows service and their small Winforms test applications.

When I build it using TFS it puts all binary files in the `Binaries` folder. It also creates a `_PublishedWebsites` folder where it puts the web applications ready for deployment.

What I would like is for a few of the projects to have their ouput in a separate directory in the `Binaries` folder. I want the files that I would normally find in the `bin\Release` folder to be there.

I looked long and hard and could only find scarce documentation on how to achieve that and only for TFS 2008. There's a good article there [link text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/aaronhallberg/) and another entry for VS 2010 there [link text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jimlamb/customizableoutdir-in-tfs-2010). However, none of these work :-(

It seems that the build ignores the `<OutputPath>` property. I tried fiddling with the `<AfterBuild>` property but unfortunately if I use the `$(OutDir)` property I get ALL the files in the `Binaries` directory and not only the ones that just got compiled.

At the moment I'm setting up a separate build that only has the projects I'm interested in that get compiled but I would really like to have all the files needed for the release built all at once.

EDIT: I didn't make it clear enough but I'm using the latest version of TFS (TFS 2010 RTM). I set up `<OutputPathDir>` on the project level as explained in the links that I provided.

Cheers.

Comment: is this TFS 2010 CTP or TFS 2008?

Comment: and where are you putting the OutputPath property that it is ignoring it?  the proper place is on the project

Answer (score 1):

In your build definition (.proj) file, check that

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
      <CustomizableOutDir>true</CustomizableOutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Also, you may run into some problems if you're trying to compile what was once a "website" project type (created from File->New->Website->ASP.NET Webiste).  They seem to override the output directory every time.  We had to convert some of those to class libraries instead.

Comment: You may have some other issues going on. CustomizableOutDir is a very disruptive flag - you should notice big changes in the build after setting that.